# ActiveMQ :Web demo not working

Tags: activemq-classic

I am a newbie to activemq stuff.I tried to run the web demos using the steps mentioned on the site  http://activemq.apache.org/web-samples.html and I am getting 404 not found.I googled for the same and tried digging through the logs as well .But my bad , I could not get any clue even  from the logs. I even copied the demo folder to the webapps folder but some of the links don’t work.
Kindly help me out with the steps to run these web demos

Comment: Are you working in Windows Platform?

Answer (score 1):

`.\bin\activemq.bat start xbean:examples/conf/activemq-demo.xml` - works perfectly fine on Windows 10. `start` was missing in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter similar issue in Windows Platform.

The documentation at [Getting Started Page](http://activemq.apache.org/version-5-getting-started.html) or [Web Sample Page](http://activemq.apache.org/web-samples.html) states how to start the ActiveMQ with examples in Linux/Unix Platform.

There is an minor issue in activemq.bat file as stated in [Apache's JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-5243). Put double quotes around `%ACTIVEMQ_CONF%\login.config` fixes this issue.

To Start ActiveMQ in Windows in unzipped apache-activemq-5.9.0 folder use the below command,

```
.\bin\activemq.bat xbean:examples/conf/activemq-demo.xml
```

I was able to open http://localhost:8161/demo/ without any Issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. It seems like

```
bin\activemq console
```

is not an option on Windows. I finally got around it by using:

```
bin/activemq start xbean:examples/conf/activemq-demo.xml
```

http://activemq.apache.org/version-5-getting-started.html#Version5GettingStarted-ActiveMQ5.9onwards